# Devise skip user confirmation for facebook does not work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, ruby-on-rails-4, oauth, devise

Devise skip user confirmation for facebook does not work. It continues to send email.

**app/models/user.rb**

```
def self.find_for_facebook_oauth(auth, signed_in_resource = nil)
    user = User.where(:provider => auth.provider, :uid => auth.uid).first
    if user
      return user
    else
      registered_user = User.where(:email => auth.info.email).first
      if registered_user
        return registered_user
      else
        user = User.create(name:auth.extra.raw_info.name,
                            provider:auth.provider,
                            uid:auth.uid,
                            email:auth.info.email,
                            password:Devise.friendly_token[0,20]
                          )
        user.skip_confirmation!
        user
      end
    end
  end
```

How can I avoid this?

Answer (score 2):

This should works:

```
def self.find_for_facebook_oauth(auth, signed_in_resource = nil)
  user = User.where(:provider => auth.provider, :uid => auth.uid).first
  if user
    return user
  else
    registered_user = User.where(:email => auth.info.email).first 

    return registered_user if registered_user

    user = User.new(
                   name:auth.extra.raw_info.name,
                   provider:auth.provider,
                   uid:auth.uid,
                   email:auth.info.email,
                   password:Devise.friendly_token[0,20]
           )
      user.skip_confirmation!
      user.save
      user
    end
  end
end
```

You need to call `skip_confirmation!` before you save the record.